# Should I make my apk signed or use the debug unsigned file?

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

In my software engineering class my team and I chose to develop an android application for our semester long project and have managed to complete our first set of iterations reaching our minimum viable system. Now that our minimum viable system is done our professor is wanting us to hand it in with a simple set of instructions on how to run the application for verification. Searching around on this site led me to a few new terms such as signing your application so that it runs on an android device. However, when referring to signing and private keystones it seems to me like signing the application is mainly for preparing for an actual release on an app store rather than for simply creating an executable version for our professor to run on an emulator or actual android device.

Being new to android development I wanted to get some feedback on how my group should hand in our application. Should we simply hand in the app.apk file from our eclipse project's bin folder, or do we actually need to export the application using a private keystone to sign our application for easy installation?

Comment: An unsigned apk won't work at all, you mean a debug signed one.  Your best bet is probably to ask the professor, as your "customer".

Comment: I already did, he basically said just to make sure what we hand in can be ran using the instructions we give him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say just hand over the apk file from the bin folder with the debug certificate. At my school this was just fine.

Signing a custom certificate is only required when releasing the app to the "real" public and to keep hackers away from creating fake updates for your app.

Comment: An unsigned apk won't work at all - you mean a debug signed one.  But be aware it will expire.

Comment: That's what I meant ;)

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the signed debug apk file will run on android devices and emulators then?

Comment: I have never had a case where it didn't run in my 5 years of Android programming.

Comment: Can't see any reason not to then. Thanks.

Comment: try to export as signed apk rather than debug file.